# In Itext, how do I flip the contents of a cell upside down?

Tags: java, rotation, itext

I have a pdfptable with some pdfpcells and this sheet is printed off and brought around with each part. When the part is on the rack, the sheets are upside down. How can I write some text into a pdfpcell and then rotate it 180 degrees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pdfpcells details here: http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Image.html

[Edit] Ignore below method, use setRotation as Dah discovered below.  Thanks for the upvote Dah, I didnt deserve it :)

You will have to create an image, draw your text to the image, translate the image to -y, or rotate the image.

Then write the image to url, and then pass that image url into the constructor for an 'com.itextpdf.text.Image'.

For drawing text in an image: [Java - Draw text in the center of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323538/java-draw-text-in-the-center-of-an-image)

[Draw the image upside down:](http://www.zetcode.com/gfx/java2d/java2dimages/)

```
g2d.translate(0, 2 * imageHeight + gap);
g2d.scale(1, -1);
```

OR

Rotate the image: [Java: Rotating Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639567/java-rotating-images)

Then:

Write an image to a file: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html

Comment: It may also be possible using unicode to draw upside down characters. http://www.fileformat.info/convert/text/upside-down-map.htm

Comment: Nah, you supplied 3 methods of doing it. I'd rather accept yours. We both screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

Apprently I missed the Oh-so-obvious PdfPCell.setRotation();